ESPNow libraries make existing code not able to compile
This is my first post: I use Wemos D1 R32 boards, ESP3 wroom. One is the transmitter and mounted in a remote location. It transmits to a receiver second esp32 that parses the data uses some and output info to a screen and the COM port.
All existing devices work. I was making new devices and the Arduino IDE wanted to update libraries. Now the programs will not compile. I tried new libraries and am not able to move forward.
The data is in a struct, less than 250 bytes.
Reddit post came up with rolling back the libraries. I looked however, did not move forward.
How do I prevent this in the future and fix the system to work again.
All existing devices work. I was making new devices and the Arduino IDE wanted to update libraries. Now the programs will not compile. I tried new libraries and am not able to move forward.
The code compiles and works without the ESPnow libraries and code.

Can you show us your code? What's the error?

I found the solution. A random Redditor recommended I roll back the Framework. I did not understand at the time. I had inadvertently clicked on upgrading to the V3.0.3 and only libraries for Version 3 were found to compile. My history of work was in ESP32 Framework 2.0.17. I rolled it back and now my code compiles and is working as I recall it did.
